# how to write the java code into matlab?

Tags: java, matlab

I have written some java code which declared as a two-dimensional dynamic array as given below :

```
 int a[][];
 a = new int[10][];
```

here a number of columns can be varied for each row.

how to write this in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option can be storing your rows in [Cell Arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Any type of data can be stored in each cell.

For example

```
a{1} = [1 2 3]
a{2} = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

then you have

```
>> a

a =

  1×2 cell array

    {1×3 double}    {1×5 double}
```

Comment: ok fine,  now I want the same thing as a dynamic way, how to create dynamic cell array.  means in java , int a [][]; a = new int [k][];

Comment: hear k  can vary by some numeric positive value

Comment: @SanjayKumarGuptaResScholar I am not sure what do you mean by "dynamic". The equivalent code in Matlab would be `a={};a=cell(k,1);`  Check [Create Cell Array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: how do I accept? I already said my problem is resolved  and your answer is helpfull , thank  you